# How can I connect specific rows in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, connect

I would like to connect specific rows in a Pandas dataframe.

I have a column „text“ and another column „name“. Each entry of the column „text“ has a string. Some entries of the column „name“ are empty so I would like to connect the row n, that has an empty entry in the column „name“ with the row (n-1). If the row (n-1) has also an empty entry in the column „name“, the rows should connect both to the next row that has an entry in the column „name“.

For example:
Input:

```
Text=["Abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu"]

Name=["a","b","c",““,““,"f","g"]
```

Expected Output:

```
Text= ["Abc","def","ghijklmno","pqr","stu"]

Name = ["a","b","c","f","g"]
```

---

I'd like to make my question more understandable:

I have two lists:

```
index = [3,6,8,9,10,12,15,17,18,19]
```

```
text = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
```

```
new = []
for i in range(0,len(text)):
    if i not in index:
        if i+1 not in index:
            new.append(text[i])
    if i in index:
        new.append(text[i-1]+' '+ text[i])
```

The list index shows the false splits of the text (when column name has no value).
Therefore, I'd like to append e.g. text[3] to text[2]. So I'll get a new entry 'c d'.

Finally, the output should be:

```
new = ['a','b,'c d','e','f g','hijk','lm','n','op','qrst','u','v','w','x','y','z']
```

These lists are just a simplified example for my large textlist. I don't know how many entries I have to connect together. My algorithm works only when I have to connect an entry n with the entry n-1. But it's also possible that I have to connect the entry n with the entries until n-10, so I get one large entry.

I hope my question is now more understandable.

Comment: Hello @albi_It. Please add DataFrame as text in your question rather than just providing some list of strings. Also add what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution now (the code doesn't look good, but the output is what I expected):

```
for i in range(0,len(text)):
    if i not in index:
        if i+1 not in index:
            new.append(text[i])
        elif i+1 in index:
            if i+2 not in index:
                new.append(text[i]+text[i+1])
            elif i+2 in index:
                if i+3 not in index:
                    new.append(text[i]+text[i+1]+text[i+2])
                elif i+3 in index:
                    if i+4 not in index:
                        new.append(text[i]+text[i+1]+text[i+2]+text[i+3])
                    elif i+4 in index:
                        if i+5 not in index:
                            new.append(text[i]+text[i+1]+text[i+2]+text[i+3]+text[i+4])
```

I have to add a few more if conditions... but for the simplified example above, the code works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace empty strings with `NaN` and Forward fill. Then `groupby` Name column and aggregate.

```
import pandas as pd

df.Name = df.Name.str.replace('', pd.np.nan).ffill()
out_df = df.groupby('Name').agg({'Text': ' '.join})
```

Comment: @albi_lt `Name` call should contain only strings.

Comment: What do you mean by not grouping by Name because you have very large list? The case you mentioned will also work with this code. @albi_lt

Answer (score 0):

by using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
   Name=["a","b","c",None,None,None,"f","g"]
    Text=["Abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu"] 

    lst=list(zip(Name,Text))

    from collections import defaultdict 

    d=defaultdict(str) 


    for i, v in lst:
        d[i] += v

    print(list(d.values()))
['Abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jklmnopqr', 'stu']
```